# How to loop through json and get a specific value?

Tags: javascript, json

I may get json as a single or multiple data source and I need to parse it to get a specific value.

How do I go about getting a specific value then putting it into a string and comparing the values to get a single string that is represented below.

```
var info;

info= {
 "rows": [
 {
  "id": 1,
  "data": [ "", "1", "s", "Al", "A" ]
 }
 ]
};

info= {
 "rows": [
 {
  "id": 1,
  "data": [ "", "1", "s", "Al", "A" ]
 },
 {
  "id": 2,
  "data": [ "", "1", "s", "Az", "A" ]
 },
 {
  "id": 3,
  "data": [ "", "2", "s", "Co", "A" ]
 }
]
};


var jsonData;
```

I'm not sure how to loop through json and extract data[1] then put each value into string such as: 1,1,2.

```
var jstring = jsonData
```

Here is my for each item that I'm trying to place into a string.

```
$.each([ jstring ], function( index, value ) {
 if(g.includes(string)) {
  console.log(value + " exists");
 }
  else
 {
  g = g + value;
 }
});
```

What I'd like to have is g looking like: 1,2

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
var outputString = info.rows.reduce(function(arr, row){
    return arr.concat(row.data[1]); 
}, []).join(",");
```

Here is a link to some docs on how reduce works:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Basically, your **rows** is an array, so reduce will apply a function to EACH item in that array, and sort of "keep track" of the output with what is called an accumulator. Our accumulator in this case is the **arr** variable. For each item in the rows array, we are concatenating that value to our accumulated array, and then passing that value to the next iteration. We pass the empty brackets as the second argument to reduce as the *initial value*, meaning we want to start with an empty array. Once reduce is finished running, we are left with an array, which in this case will look like [1,1,2]. At that point, we can use .join(",") to join each item in our new array into a string, separated by a comma.

Comment: I got this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined

Comment: I think a filter should be applied as well to remove duplicates.

Comment: how would I iterate through the json to find the array value for the column of 1?

Comment: okay so I've been working on trying to get data from the json data but am now stuck at a point where I can see the next section but still can't get to the data element that is needed. Here is what i have so far:  var keys = [];     for (var key in info) {  console.log(key); //return  rows  if (info.hasOwnProperty(key)) { var val = info[key]; console.log(val); //returns  [object] for (var key2 in val) {  if     (val.hasOwnProperty(key2)) {   var val2 = val[key2];   console.log(val2); //returns  object{id:1, data: Array[5]}   //get value of data.1 which is 1  } }  }      }

Comment: i added a loop after this: //get value of data.1 which is 1. inside that i have: for (var i=0; i<val2.data.length; i++) {   console.log(val2.data[1]); //returns 1   }     So now i can read one but how would I handle multiples?